# React Native condition is not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the bellow code- log return "true" but condition is not working. Can anyone know what is wrong going on here?

```
componentDidMount() {
        TimerMixin.setTimeout(
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.loginStatus);
            if( this.state.loginStatus == "true" ){
              console.log("go to inner");
              //this._onPress();
            }
            console.log(this.state.loginStatus);
          },
          300
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing boolean (`loginStatus`) to string. Remove quotes, e.g. `loginStatus == true` and also use `===` instead of `==`. You can also just do `if(this.state.loginStatus)`.

Comment: This is already working for me "if(this.state.loginStatus)". Sorry for late reply. But I have assigned the value in string( In JSON) .... Although if(this.state.responseData.status.status == "true") this is working for me... Really confusing.

Comment: Remember to use `===` instead of `==`!